# Pyinstaller windowed problems

Tags: python, pyqt, subprocess, exe, pyinstaller

I'm currently having a problem with pyinstaller 3.5, I wrote a script using Pyqt and Subprocess which I package into an .exe using pyinstaller. If I pack the .exe without the argument --windowed the script works fine. Once I pass --windowed as argument nothing works. Debugging is not really possible anymore because I have no output. Anyone an idea if it makes any sense this error?

Comment: You can enter debug mode where all print/error outputs will be shown on the command line by using `pyinstaller --onefile <filename.py>`. Note you have to open the program using the command line, double clicking the program will not work.

Comment: I know. Script works absolutely fine with pyinstaller --onefile <filename.py>. But as i add --windowed the script doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

More info would be probably needed to spot the issue.

1.

There are some points to take care of when using `pyinstaller + subprocess`.
I would recommend to [check this page](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-subprocess), main points being:

> subprocess.Popen will pop up a command window by default when run from Pyinstaller with the --noconsole option.
>
> Windows doesn't search the path by default.
>
> Running this from the binary produced by Pyinstaller with the --noconsole option requires redirecting everything (stdin, stdout, stderr) to avoid an OSError exception: "[Error 6] the handle is invalid."

2.

Then, for debugging purpose, you can try to run pyinstaller with the debug option (doc is [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#how-to-generate)):

`pyinstaller --debug=all`

This could point you in the right direction.

3.

Finally, some `sys.stdout` code could also prevent the `exe` from running in `--windowed` mode, like:

```
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
#or
sys.stdout = open(sys.stdout.fileno(), mode='w', encoding='utf8', buffering=1)
```

In this case, using the following code to change `sys.stdout` encoding might help:

```
if sys.stdout.encoding != 'UTF-8':
    sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout.buffer, 'strict')
if sys.stderr.encoding != 'UTF-8':
    sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stderr.buffer, 'strict')
```